# undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: python, linux, pycurl

Hi I am getting following error while installing pycurl (pip install pycurl)

We are using CentOS release 6.4

pycurl is in requirement.txt, but it fails even if I try to install it separately.

```
src/pycurl.h:152:5: warning: #warning "libcurl was compiled with SSL support, but configure could not determine which " "library was used; thus no SSL crypto locking callbacks will be set, which may " "cause random crashes on SSL requests"

src/module.c: In function ‘initpycurl’:

src/module.c:723: error: ‘CURLPROTO_IMAP’ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/module.c:723: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

src/module.c:723: error: for each function it appears in.)

src/module.c:724: error: ‘CURLPROTO_IMAPS’ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/module.c:725: error: ‘CURLPROTO_POP3’ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/module.c:726: error: ‘CURLPROTO_POP3S’ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/module.c:727: error: ‘CURLPROTO_SMTP’ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/module.c:728: error: ‘CURLPROTO_SMTPS’ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/module.c:729: error: ‘CURLPROTO_RTSP’ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/module.c:730: error: ‘CURLPROTO_RTMP’ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/module.c:731: error: ‘CURLPROTO_RTMPT’ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/module.c:732: error: ‘CURLPROTO_RTMPE’ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/module.c:733: error: ‘CURLPROTO_RTMPTE’ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/module.c:734: error: ‘CURLPROTO_RTMPS’ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/module.c:735: error: ‘CURLPROTO_RTMPTS’ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/module.c:736: error: ‘CURLPROTO_GOPHER’ undeclared (first use in this function)

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/pycurl/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Uf0WAn-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pycurl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.6.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.6.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is the complete trace http://pastebin.com/PvtAgQtj

Any workaround this issue ?

Comment: Which distro (and version) are you using? Have you installed your distro's equivalent of `curl-dev`, `openssl-dev`, and the other requirements for `pycurl`?

Comment: You may need to install/update the (C language) development package, for curl, which should contain the header file that defines those symbols that GCC is complaining about. Can you try to package-install "libcurl-dev" or some similar-sounding package?

Comment: Also note the last paragraph here: http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/install.html#distutils - you may need to work out how to tell it want SSL backend you're using.

Comment: curl-dev, openssl-dev installed, don't know if I am missing any requirement

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/issues/201) from the pycurl which mentions that upgrading the curl library is the way to go.

Comment: I have libcurl-7.19.7-40.el6_6.1.x86_64 installed